# Data does not get persisted

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

What is wrong with the following piece of code?

```
    @PrePersist
    public void preSave() throws DuplicatePinException  {
        Logger.info("PRESAVE");
        for (PinBoard pb : board.pins) {
            if (pb.pin.id.equals(this.pin.id)) {
                throw new DuplicatePinException();
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is in my PinBoard class. I wanted a quick way to validate that no duplicate entries can be saved. If I include the method, however, nothing gets saved. Ever. I traced it down to the `board.pins`. I assume that pins is a lazy loaded collection by default, so it might be that forcing it to initialize at the time of saving is screwing up something.

I am using Play 1.2.5

Comment: Is the console print the log `Logger.info("PRESAVE")`?

Comment: @iwawiwi yes, it does

Comment: Okay. If you do `List<PinBoard> piboard_list = board.pins` before loop. and loop over `pinboard_list` is it still not persist? If still not work. I would recomended you to put validation code in the controller and do that before calling `save()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about play 1 but in play 2 @PrePersist is not included, so method is never getting called